# Integrate a Generalized incomplete gamma function

Tags: calculus, analysis, special-functions, gamma-function

My question is about an integral but not an ordinary one

$\int_{le^{-bt'}}^{l}s^{l-1}e^{-s}ds$

I have the idea of use the leibniz integral rule because I don't want to use the Generalized incomplete gamma function but when I used the integral becomes more difficult i think because the result of use the leibniz rule is:

$\int_{le^{-bt'}}^{l}s^{l-1}e^{-s}ds=l^{l-1}e^{-l}-\left(le^{-bt'}\right)^{l-1}e^{-le^{-bt'}}e^{-bt'}+\int_{le^{-bt'}}^{l}s^{l-1}e^{-s}ln(s)ds$

I hope someone can help my with the last integral